# 'TypeError object is not a function' when tapping <button> in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, typeerror, string-concatenation, angularjs-ng-click

I have a problem with a button who gave me an error message in the DOM console. The error message is:

TypeError: object is not a function
    at angular.js:10822
    at angular.js:19062
    at k.$eval (angular.js:12658)
    at k.$apply (angular.js:12756)
    at HTMLFormElement. (angular.js:19061)
    at angular.js:2843
    at r (angular.js:325)
    at HTMLFormElement.c (angular.js:2842)

I am using AngularJS and here is my HTML code:

```
<!-- partial-contact.html -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div id="form-container">
        <!-- Contact Heading -->
        <div class="page-header text-center">
            <h1><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Kontakt</h1>
            <p>Ved spørsmål skriv ein epost i kontaktskjemaet under.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Form -->
        <!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
        <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" novalidate ng-submit="contactForm()" ng-controller="contactController" method="post">
        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input id="personName" class="form-control" type="text" name="personName" ng-model="contactData.personName" placeholder="Namn *" required />
        </div>
        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
            <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="contactData.email" placeholder="Epost *" required />
        </div>
        <!-- Subject -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></span>
            <input id="subject" class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" ng-model="contactData.subject" placeholder="Emne *" required />
        </div>
        <!-- Email Message & Button -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <!-- Email Message -->
                <textarea id="emailMessage" type="text" class="form-control" name="emailMessage" ng-model="contactData.emailMessage" ng-minlength=10 ng-maxlength=300 placeholder="Melding..." required></textarea>
                <!-- Button -->
                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendMessage('#/path/' + obj.val1 + '/' + 'obj.val2' + '/' + 'obj.val3' + '/' + 'obj.val4')"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
                debug: {{debug.val}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if the problem is the ng-click method in the -element and it doesn't work with ng-submit in the -element. May anyone see any other errors in my code?

Here is my controller:

```
// contact controller
eventApp.controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.obj = {
        val1: '$scope.personName',
        val2: '$scope.email',
        val3: '$scope.subject',
        val4: '$scope.emailMessage'
    };
    $scope.debug = {
        val: ''
    };
    $scope.sendMessage = function(input) {
        $scope.debug.val = input;
    };
}]);
```

I got my inspiration from this link:

[concat scope variables into string in angular directive expresssion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186751/concat-scope-variables-into-string-in-angular-directive-expresssion)

Comment: I would suggest that you leave the string building from your function to the `.js` file, because you shouldn't leave the logic in the html file, just pass the object in `ng-click`, i.e. `sendMessage(obj)`, and then build the string inside the function.

Comment: Yeah, what @MichelTomé said. It is harder to manage and debug, and you want minimal JS mixed with your HTML. Also, it will interpret `obj.val1` as the string "$scope.personName" not evaluating it. Can you put this up in a simple jsfiddle that will show the error?

Comment: Do you get the error when *clicking* the button or when the html first *loads*?

Comment: Simplified fiddle here works fine http://jsfiddle.net/wpza5pu3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it that way, pass the object in the function `sendMessage(obj)`, and then in your js just do:

```
$scope.obj = {
    val1: 'personName',
    val2: 'email',
    val3: 'subject',
    val4: 'emailMessage'
};
$scope.sendMessage = function(obj) {
    var string = '#/path/' + $scope[obj.val1] + '/' + $scope[obj.val2] + '/' + $scope[obj.val3] + '/' + $scope[obj.val4];
    $scope.debug.val = string;
};
```

JavaScript `objects` are treated like `arrays`, so `$scope[obj.val1]` == `$scope.personName`, because of the value of `$scope.obj.val1`.