# How to mix angularjs in laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am developing a web app , using laravel for back end and angular for frond end . I have fetched an array from my App API and displaying that in view using angular as shown below. But now i have to buttons for each records i.e EDIT and delete . These two buttons need ID but how to grab the ID . Actually laravel blade syntax throws error when i embed angular in there.

> Error : Use of undefined constant student - assumed 'student'
>   **syntax error, unexpected '{'**

**View**

```
<tbody ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchText">
                                  <tr> 
                                    <td>@{{ student.rollno }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.name }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.fname }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.obtainedmarks }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.totalmarks }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.percentage }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {!! Form::open(array('url' => "/result/ @{{ student.id }}/edit" , 'method' => 'GET')) !!}
                                            {!! Form::hidden('id',  @{{ student.id }}) !!}
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/result/destroy' , 'files'=>true, 'method' => 'delete')) !!}
                                        {!! Form::hidden('id', @{{ student.id }} ) !!}
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                        <hr>
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using double quotes in PHP, it'll consider anything between curly brackets as code injected into the string, which is why fx. this will throw an error:

```
"/result/@{{ student.id }}/edit"
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ PHP will think this is injected, ultimately it'll be
//                        interpreted exactly like if you did this:
"/result/@" . { student.id } . "/edit" // < Which is  not valid PHP
```

You should be able to get it working using single quotes:

```
<tbody ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchText">
<tr>
    <td>@{{ student.rollno }}</td>
    <td>@{{ student.name }}</td>
    <td>@{{ student.fname }}</td>
    <td>@{{ student.obtainedmarks }}</td>
    <td>@{{ student.totalmarks }}</td>
    <td>@{{ student.percentage }}</td>
    <td>
        {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/result/@{{ student.id }}/edit' , 'method' => 'GET')) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('id',  '@{{ student.id }}') !!}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </td>
    <td>
        {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/result/destroy' , 'files'=>true, 'method' => 'delete')) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('id', '@{{student.id}}' ) !!}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <hr>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: throws this error ` Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fngresulty%2Fpublic%2Fresult%2F%7B%7B%20student.id%20%7D%7D%2Fedit at Error (native)`

Comment: So now we moved from a PHP error to an angular error. It seems that it doesn't wanna inject a variable into a string. It seems [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186751/concat-scope-variables-into-string-in-angular-directive-expresssion) is experiencing something like it; they suggest creating a scope function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the blade and angular echo syntax, here is an example of changing the angular syntax:

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%').endSymbol('%>');
});
```

You can now output angular variables like so

```
<% student.name %>
```